# Auto Save File extension for Visual Studio repeatedly displays file save dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I add a table in Visual Studio's  SQL Server Object Explorer then a file save dialog pops up to save the SQL query:

[image]

I'm saving the file but it doesn't help. Every time when the query window loses focus this window pops up again.

How can I turn off this pop up window?

Comment: @Yogi
Please watch carefully. I've clicked 'yes' and 'No' but it did not help. I've already find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the error is caused by the [Auto Save File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HRai.AutoSaveFile&ssr=false#overview) extension (it saves any script if the window loses focus).

To fix the problem I just exclude `sql` files saving:

[image]